# How do I join two video files in my iPhone application using FFMPEG?

Tags: iphone, ffmpeg

I would like to join two video files within my iPhone application using the FFMPEG library, but I can't figure out how to do this.  Does anyone have any experience with this?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunatley, if you planning to release your app to the App Store, you won't be able to use libavcodec since it is licensed under GPL. However, there is tutorial in the [FFmpeg docs](http://www.ffmpeg.org/faq.html#SEC27) on how join two files if that is any help.